# how do I check if an item is already in array before adding it to array using Angular?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular

I want to check if there is an item inside of the array with the same 'datum'. If that is the case I want the program to do nothing, but if that's not the case I want it to add it to my array.

I already have the following code. this just gets the data from input fields in the html, and places the data inside the array.

I only need to check if there's already an item inside with the same 'datum', but I have no idea how to get this done.

```
store(newValue:number, newDatum, newAanwezig, newComment){
    let billable = new BillableHours();
    billable.datum = newDatum;
    billable.hours = +newValue;
    billable.aanwezig = newAanwezig;
    billable.comment = newComment;

    if(billable.aanwezig == "Aanwezig" && billable.hours !== null && billable.datum !== null) {
      this.urenRegistratie.push(billable);
    }

  }
```

Comment: What about tu use Set: let set = new Set(); on urenRegistratie object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Find in your array if there is an item with that datum already. 
const existingDatum = this.urenRegistratie.find(billable => {
  return billable.datum === newDatum;
});

// If you don't have an existing item with the same  datum, then you can create and add it to the array
if (!existingDatum) {
    let billable = new BillableHours();
    billable.datum = newDatum;
    billable.hours = +newValue;
    billable.aanwezig = newAanwezig;
    billable.comment = newComment;

    if(billable.aanwezig == "Aanwezig" && billable.hours !== null && billable.datum !== null) {
      this.urenRegistratie.push(billable);
    }
}
```

Read more about [JS Array Find here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/javascript-array-find-method/#:~:targetText=The%20Array.find()%20is,condition%20is%20going%20to%20print.)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

In the future: Say you wanted to modify or update the existing object that already has datum with the new data. You could use map to return a new array with the modified item inside the callback

Answer (score 2):

```
if (urenRegistratie.some(e => e.datum === newDatum)) {
/* contains the element we're looking for */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use 'find' or 'findIndex' as follow:

with 'findIndex':

```
store(newValue:number, newDatum, newAanwezig, newComment){
    let billable = new BillableHours();
    billable.datum = newDatum;
    billable.hours = +newValue;
    billable.aanwezig = newAanwezig;
    billable.comment = newComment;

    if(billable.aanwezig == "Aanwezig" && billable.hours !== null && billable.datum !== null && this.urenRegistratie.findIndex(f=>f.datum ==billable.datum)>-1) {
      this.urenRegistratie.push(billable);
    }

  }
```

or 'find'

```
store(newValue:number, newDatum, newAanwezig, newComment){
    let billable = new BillableHours();
    billable.datum = newDatum;
    billable.hours = +newValue;
    billable.aanwezig = newAanwezig;
    billable.comment = newComment;

    if(billable.aanwezig == "Aanwezig" && billable.hours !== null && billable.datum !== null && !this.urenRegistratie.find(f=>f.datum ==billable.datum)) {
      this.urenRegistratie.push(billable);
    }

  }
```

Good Luck!!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use **some()** to do it.

Try like this:

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ts1kgb?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts)**

```
let billable = { aanwezig: "Aanwezig", hours: 12 }
if (!this.urenRegistratie.some(x => x.aanwezig == billable.aanwezig && x.hours == billable.hours)) {
  this.urenRegistratie.push(billable);
}
```

Comment: Since it's Angular (typescript), it's a good practice to do strict check: `index` **`===`** `-1`.

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
let billable = new BillableHours();
    billable.datum = newDatum;
    billable.hours = +newValue;
    billable.aanwezig = newAanwezig;
    billable.comment = newComment;
var flag = false;
this.urenRegistratie.forEach(elem => {
    if(elem.datum === newDatum){
      flag = true;
    }
});
if(billable.aanwezig == "Aanwezig" && billable.hours !== null && billable.datum !== null) {
if(!flag){
this.urenRegistratie.push(billable);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Array.prototype.find()` function to see if there is already an entry with the same `datum` value. If not found, it will return `undefined` and if found you get the array element that matched. The code would look like this:

```
let element = this.urenRegistratie.find(e => e.datum === newDatum);
if(element) {
 // Found, update it 
}
else {
 // Not found insert new 
 this.urenRegistratie.push(new {})
}
```

See [Array.prototype.find documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) for full details.